# DatetimeIndex cannot perform the operation mean

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, seaborn

I'm trying to implement a line of best fit to a plot from a pandas Dataframe.

I get the error 'DatetimeIndex cannot perform the operation mean' and this is what my dataframe looks like:

```
      date  new builds  new houses  new homes  help to buy  
0   2014-06-08       4          29         79           12   
1   2014-06-15       4          31         79           11   
2   2014-06-22       5          31         80           12   
3   2014-06-29       5          29         81           11   
4   2014-07-06       5          31         82           12   
5   2014-07-1        5          33         82           12   
6   2014-07-20       4          32         85           12   
7   2014-07-2        5          33         89           13
```

This is the code i'm using to try and plot a line of best fit

```
sns.regplot(x='date',y='new builds',data=data, fit_reg=True)
```